# method range of object _worksheet failed- BUT works when I hit "Run sub (F5)"

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit stumped, cant find a solution on the web, maybe I am just googling wrong.
This bit of code gives me the following error - *method range of object _worksheet failed*

```
With WSCC
    .Activate
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Createcomplex1", Range:=.Range("F4:F5,F7,B4:B7,B9:B11,B14,B17:C23")
    .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Createcomplex2", Range:=.Range("B27:E41,B44:E53,C56:E58,C63:E67,H11:H2010")
    .Protect Password:="protectsheetpassword"
End With
```

WSCC is defined as a Worksheet - Public WSCC as worksheet

It used to be a single range with Title "Createcomplex1", then I split it to 2 ranges, but still happens.  **The real kicker, it gives me an error, then I hit Debug and simply click the "Play" aka Run sub (F5) button and it continues and performs the code perfectly, without me having made any changes.**

A a side-note, code already deletes all Alloweditranges just before this code, so no duplication problems

Comment: Such a behavior may happen if a previous action has not been finished when the code reaches the line involving the object not (yet) disappeared...  Try please adding 'DoEvents` in front of `With WSCC`.

Comment: I added Do Events right before ```With WSCC``` - it has no effect

Comment: Please, try adding `DoEvents` after the `End With`, too...

Comment: Did that, no effect.  I did realize that if i create a separate line  for each range like this ```.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Createcomplex2", Range:=.Range("B27:E41")``` it works, it requires multiple lines and like 15 separate Alloweditranges, but it still doesn't make sense

Comment: It would make sense only if the property in discussion does not allow discontinuous ranges. Try such a shorter discontinuous range, please.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I tried shortening it at first, split it into 2, then 4 and so on, but the error keeps popping up all the same.